# How to plot two variables side by side in the same ggplot using geom_col?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, geom-col

I have the following data

```
structure(list(id = 1:7, date = c(2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L), station = structure(1:7, .Label = c("41B004", 
"41B011", "41MEU1", "41N043", "41R001", "41R012", "41WOL1"), class = "factor"), 
    days = c(6L, 21L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 14L, 3L), mean3y = c(8.33, 
    21.3, NA, 10, 11.3, 16.3, 3.67), environ = structure(c(3L, 
    4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Industriel avec influence modérée du trafic", 
    "Urbain avec faible influence du trafic", "Urbain avec influence modérée du trafic", 
    "Urbain avec très faible influence du trafic"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

which is plotted with the following ggplot code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(station, -days), 
                 y = days, fill = environ)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, colour = "black", size = 0.5) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = days), 
            vjust=-0.3, color="black", size = 3.5) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 25), 
             linetype = 'dashed', colour = 'red', size = 1) +
  labs(x = '', y = bquote("Nombre de jours de dépassement de NET60" ~ O[3] ~ "en 2019")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.margin=margin(l = -2, unit='line'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

generating this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tliP5.png).

I would like to also add in this figure the variable `mean3y` besides `days` for each x value using another `geom_col`, such as

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = reorder(station, -days), 
                      y = days, fill = environ)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5, colour = "black", size = 0.5) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = days), 
            vjust=-0.3, color="black", size = 3.5) +
  geom_col(aes(x = reorder(station, -days), 
               y = mean3y, fill = environ), 
           inherit.aes = FALSE,
           width = 0.5, colour = "black", size = 0.5) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 25), 
             linetype = 'dashed', colour = 'red', size = 1) +
  labs(x = '', y = bquote("Nombre de jours de dépassement de NET60" ~ O[3] ~ "en 2019")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom", 
        legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.margin=margin(l = -2, unit='line'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

However, I was not able to achieve the desired result, despite the use of `position = "dodge"`, as illustrated by this [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeJVE.png) where both variables are overlapping.

Is there a way to achieve this, please ?
Many thanks.

Comment: can you post data that can be directly read into R session ? use dput maybe

Answer (score 3):

Position dodges only work in a single layer and not between multiple layers. You could either solve the problem by manually nudging them or by formatting the data in such a way that it can be dodged. Examples of both in code below.

Your data was hard to copy into my R session and your code was more elaborate than necessary to demonstrate the problem, so I've kept both to a minimum.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c("A", "B"), 
  y = c(10, 15),
  z = c(12, 9)
)

# Example of nudging
# Choose width and nudge values manually to fit your data
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = "first col"), 
           width = 0.45,
           position = position_nudge(x = -0.225)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = z, fill = "second_col"), 
           width = 0.45,
           position = position_nudge(x = 0.225))
```

[image]

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Example of dodging + data formatting
ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col(data = rbind(mutate(df, a = "first_col"),
                        mutate(df, y = z, a = "second_col")),
           aes(fill = a),
           position = "dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to convert the data to long format via e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer`, so that the variables we want to plot are categories of one variable. To get the order of the stations right I reorder `station` according to `days` before converting to long. To get the bars side-by-side I use `position_dodge2` both in `geom_col` and `geom_text`. To show which bar corresponds to which var I put the names of the vars in the labels above the bars.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data1 <- data %>% 
  mutate(station = forcats::fct_reorder(station,-days)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(days, mean3y), names_to = "var", values_to = "value")

my_labels <- function(x) {
  gsub("(days.|mean3y.)", "", x)
}

    p <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = station, y = value, fill = environ)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"), colour = "black") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(var, "\n", value)), position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single"), vjust=-0.3, color="black", size = 3.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = my_labels) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 25), linetype = 'dashed', colour = 'red', size = 1) +
  labs(x = '', y = bquote("Nombre de jours de dépassement de NET60" ~ O[3] ~ "en 2019")) +
  theme_minimal() + theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), legend.margin=margin(l = -2, unit='line'),
                          legend.text = element_text(size = 11),
                          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11), 
                          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11),
                          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider this possible solution for your dataset - although you may want to play around with the aesthetics.  I attempted to keep the aesthetics as similar as possible and set the bars to be the same color (based on `df$environ`), but make the difference between "days" and "mean3y" clear with text labels.

**Data Preparation**

First, we need to take the information from two columns and combine them: "days" and "mean3y".  In your original data frame, these two columns can (and should) be combined to show *type* of value and the *value itself*.  What we want to do is convert this type of data:

```
  day.type.1 day.type.2
1          4          1
2          5          3
3          6          4
4          7          5
```

To this type of data:

```
    day.type day.value
1 day.type.1         4
2 day.type.1         5
3 day.type.1         6
4 day.type.1         7
5 day.type.2         1
6 day.type.2         3
7 day.type.2         4
8 day.type.2         5
```

In the above example, you can use the `gather()` function from `dplyr`:

```
t %>% gather('day.type', 'day.value')
```

If we apply that to your data frame, we have to specify to do that to the data frame, *but ignore the other columns*:

```
df1 <- df %>% gather('variable', 'value', -date, -station, -environ)
```

This converts your "days" and "mean3y" columns into two new columns called "variable" (which is either "days" or "mean3y") and "value" (which is the actual number)

I also had to convert the new column "value" into numeric... but that could have been due to how I had to import your data, which was... difficult.  Please note, it is recommended that you include your dataset in future questions via the output of `dput(your.data.frame)`... believe me it makes all the difference.  ;)

**Plotting the new Dataset**

Here the idea is to keep your same x axis, but we are now setting "value" as the y aesthetic.  In addition, you want to make sure to include a `group=` aesthetic of "variable" so that dodging works appropriately for text and columns.  If you are not familiar, "dodging" is the term for when a geom is kind of "split" across an axis aesthetic: like "subsetting" of discrete axis values.

The `geom_col` call is set for `position='dodge'`... not much else changes there.  You need this because the default `position` is set to "stacked" (which is why your attempt resulted in columns "stacked" on top of one another.

The `geom_text` call has a few things going on:

- The dodge is set here with `position=position_dodge()`, which allows you to specify how far apart the "dodge" will be.  It allowed me to "push apart" the labels to be a bit wider so that the text looks okay and doesn't run into the adjacent column.  A larger `width=` argument in `position_dodge()` results in "pushing" the labels further apart.  A value of 0 would be putting the labels in the center of the x axis aesthetic... 0.5 is default.
- The label aesthetic is actually using both "variable" and "value" columns as a way to differentiate your columns from one another.  I used `paste0` and stuck a `'\n'` in-between so that you had two lines and could fit them.  Had to adjust the size a bit too.
- By default, the labels would be positioned right at y (value), which would mean they would overlap with your columns.  You need to "nudge" them up, but cannot use `nudge_y` to push them up because you cannot combine `nudge_y` with `position`.  What to do?  Well, we can just overwrite the default y aesthetic by setting it equal to y + "a number" to nudge them up.  Much better to do it this way.

Here's the final code:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = reorder(station, -value),
                 y = value, fill = environ,
                group=variable)) + 
    geom_col(width = 0.5, colour = "black", size = 0.5, position='dodge') + 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = paste0(variable,'\n', value), y=value+1.5), 
              color="black", size = 3,
              position=position_dodge(0.7)) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 25), 
               linetype = 'dashed', colour = 'red', size = 1) +
    labs(x = '', y = bquote("Nombre de jours de dépassement de NET60" ~ O[3] ~ "en 2019")) +
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), 
          legend.margin=margin(l = -2, unit='line'),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 11),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 11), 
          axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

[image]